# How to get screen state(on/off) in jni?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to get screen on/off state with jni programming,but I only provide .so file to customer,customer will not give me screen state through java call,Can I get it in JNI directly?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In general, anything that you can get from .so should be available via JNI as well.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023

You have there sample code that will call some other code via JNI wrapper. If you can provide screen status via .so there should be no problem with accessing this information via JNI.